# x265 MKV videos play back with jumps and stutters on my PC. What do I need to upgrade to make movies run smoothly?

Tags: video, graphics-card, video-playback

[Here is a test sample MKV video](http://downloads.4ksamples.com/downloads/SES.Astra.UHD.Test.2.2160p.UHDTV.HEVC.x265-LiebeIst.mkv) I am using and I use and [here is another test MKV video I am using](http://downloads.4ksamples.com/downloads/SES.Astra.UHD.Test.1.2160p.UHDTV.AAC.HEVC.x265-LiebeIst.mkv). These MKV videos are compressed with x265 codec with a resolution of 2160p.

It stutters and jumps on my computer when I watch it. No other processes are working. My OS is Windows-7 32 bit and I am using the latest version of [MPC-HC](https://mpc-hc.org/) with default presets and initial range of codecs. My video card is a Quadro 2000 with 1GB of RAM and computer RAM is 4GB.

I use full-HD display (1080p), so it should scale down on the way. I'm watching 1080p movies fine on my computer compressed with the same codec.

Video processors are a bit confusing because they don't have a linear scale for performance, that is why I like G3D Mark, so My video card gives me a [videocard benchmark score of 1315](https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=Quadro%202000&id=1543).

What do I need to upgrade to make movies run smoothly?

Comment: I tried it on Intel i7-3520M with 16Gig or RAM and Video of Nvidia Quadro K1000M with 2G of video RAM and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to my question. It is clear that I need an upgrade but it is not clear what exactly I need. I'm not in a position to buy the best on the shelf computer. So the plan is to find a minimum requirement and then buy something a little bit more powerful.

Comment: Maybe instead of adding you want to remove something, some other driver, perhaps. Try to run DPC latency checker (google) while playing the video to see if there is a clear culprit.

Comment: Both the examples were downloaded and played on a laptop with Intel Core i7-4700 and *onboard* video. Using MPC-HC, *SES.Astra.UHD.Test.2.2160p.UHDTV.HEVC.x265-LiebeIst.mkv* played fairly smoothly when the PC was not heavily loaded, but skipped frames in action scenes when another process used ~85% CPU time. The files were converted to MP4 keeping the same frame rate and size using VLC and played flawlessly whether the CPU was loaded or not. Workaround: convert to MP4. The MP4 files were about 3/4 the size of the MKV, so there is some (lossy?) compression.